# Import large csv file with laravel excel and postgresql

Tags: laravel, postgresql, csv, laravel-excel

Hi I have a large csv file with 130.000 rows

I use laravel excel 3.1 and lavaravel 5.8

Import class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\UsoSuelo;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;

class UsoSueloImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithChunkReading, WithBatchInserts
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new UsoSuelo([
            'cod_pais'     => $row['cod_pais'],
            'cod_fundo'     => $row['cod_fundo'],
            'nom_fundo'     => $row['nom_fundo'],

        ]);
    }
    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }
    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

And I use a trait class from my controller:

```
    trait storeTrait{

    public function storeUsoSuelo($archivo) {
        Excel::import(new UsoSueloImport,$archivo); 
    }
    public function storeFundo($archivo) {
        Excel::import(new FundosImport,$archivo); 
    }
    public function storeFundoGrilla($archivo) {
        Excel::import(new FundosGrillasImport,$archivo); 
    }
    public function storeCuadrante($archivo) {
        Excel::import(new CuadrantesImport,$archivo); 
    }
}
```

This is my ImportController

```
class ImportController extends Controller
{
    use storeTrait  {
        storeUsoSuelo as storeUsoSuelos;
        storeFundo as storeFundos;
        storeFundoGrilla as storeFundoGrillas;
        storeCuadrante as storeCuadrantes;

    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $usoSuelo = 'uso_suelo.csv';
        $this->storeUsoSuelos($usoSuelo);

        $cuadrante = 'cuadrantes.csv';
        $this->storeCuadrantes($cuadrante);

        $fundo = 'mv_qav_fundos.csv';
        $this->storeFundos($fundo);

        $fundoGrilla = 'fundos_grilla.csv';
        $this->storeFundoGrillas($fundoGrilla);
}
}
```

I have done tests and my code works with a csv of less than 100 rows
but when I try with the 130,000 rows it takes too long, and I end up getting the following error:

```
"Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"
```

And after 1 minute only 4000 rows have been inserted in the database (postgresql)

Comment: You need to use a queued job to process the csv. The execution time error is from the `max_execution_time` PHP setting.

Comment: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/queued.html

Comment: Hello, if I understand, it happens that my maximum time is as follows:
max_execution_time = 240

Try the suggestion you gave me, but neither, only 4000 rows are imported after 1 minute and I get the error I mentioned again http://prntscr.com/s6yxnu

Comment: There are thousands of questions here on SO about long running PHP processes, if you search for your error msg, or something like "long running PHP process" you'll find some of them.  Fiddling with `max_execution_time` etc is a hacky workaround.  If you're using Laravel, you already have the standard solution built in and at your fingertips - [use queues](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues).  Another option is to write a PHP script to [run on the console](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan), rather than in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put these 2 lines in my controller, at the beginning of the script:

```
ini_set ('max_execution_time', 3600);
ini_set ('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

With this I solved it, I also changed the chunk from 1000 to 5000, but it still takes too long, at least 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this package `league/csv` from [The League of Extraordinary Packages](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv).

If you only need support for CSV that is, and not xlsx or other excel types.
From what I read this package might give you a better performance, [this comment](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1965#issuecomment-455217400) from one of the Maatwebsite team members (the package you are currently using) also confirms this.